# How can I accesss to the elements of array objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, jquery-plugins

How Can I get data from this json data ?

I get this data from the server, and it sends some database's datas by using sequelize.

Data what I want to access is

```
{result: "[{"userid":"a","speed":10},{"userid":"b","speed":20},{"userid":"c","speed":30}]"}]" }
```

And I tried `console.log(result[0].userid);`

But, I only got errer like this. `' Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'userid' of undefined'`.

Could you tell me what I have to fix?

Comment: `JSON.parse(result)`

Comment: @Adam - not sure how that is going to help on invalid JSON formatting

Answer (score 1):

You gave an invalid JSON, the json should be something like this:

Formatted JSON Data

```
{
  "result":[
    {
      "userid":"a",
      "speed":10
    },
    {
      "userid":"b",
      "speed":20
    },
    {
      "userid":"c",
      "speed":30
    }
  ]
}
```

And after that you can access it:

```js
const json = {
  "result":[
    {
      "userid":"a",
      "speed":10
    },
    {
      "userid":"b",
      "speed":20
    },
    {
      "userid":"c",
      "speed":30
    }
  ]
};

console.log(json.result[0].userid);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is badly formatted.

Try this instead...

```
{"result":[{"userid":"a","speed":10},{"userid":"b","speed":20},{"userid":"c","speed":30}]}
```

The main issues were...

```
{result: "[{"userid"
```

Should be...

```
{"result":[{"userid"
```

And

```
"speed":30}]"}]" }
```

Should be...

```
"speed":30}]}
```

Please note, the whitespace between the items makes no difference, but I have remove to reduce the size of the JSON string